# variable gets double value by applying an if/else statement

Tags: java, if-statement

I have an issue with the following method. If I apply the `if/else` condition which is currently set as a comment `/* */`, the variable `withdrawalAmountVar` get double value (if balance is 100 and I withdraw 1 final balance is 98, if I withdraw 10 the final balance is 80). Why?

```
public void makeWithdrawalButton()
{
    //transfer user's input into withdrawalAmountVar
    withdrawalAmountVar = Integer.parseInt(text5.getText());

    //check if withdrawal should be allowed according to overdraft set
/*
if ( (moneyAmountVar -= withdrawalAmountVar) < overdraftVar)
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Withdrawal amount exceeds overdraft" );
    text5.setText("");
}

else
{
*/

    try
    {
        //make withdrawal from current deposit amount
        moneyAmountVar -= withdrawalAmountVar;

        output = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("datafile.dat") );
        output.writeInt(accountNumberVar);
        output.writeUTF(firstNameVar);
        output.writeUTF(lastNameVar);
        output.writeInt(moneyAmountVar);
        output.close();
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        System.err.println( "Cannot make withdrawal");
        System.exit(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: you are executing twice `moneyAmountVar -= withdrawalAmountVar`

One in if condition and
another in starting of try block

Comment: moneyAmountVar-= actually changes the value

Comment: your `if` condition is `moneyAmountVar -= withdrawalAmountVar`, and the you again do `moneyAmountVar -= withdrawalAmountVar`. `a -= b` means `a = a - b`

Comment: I tried to insert inside the "if" statement: moneyAmountVar += withdrawalAmountVar to see if changes anything, but it does not. Anyway a math operation inside an if statement is going to be "permanently" executed??

Comment: the operation changes the value . even if its in a test case(conditional)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is

```
if ( (moneyAmountVar -= withdrawalAmountVar) < overdraftVar)
```

because you used the operation -= you are actually changing the value of moneyAmountVar to moneyAmountVar-withdrawalAmountVar. When you use this operation or something like it, the lValue will always change accordingly, no matter if it is in a conditional or loop.
To Fix:

```
int temp = moneyAmountVar - withdrawalAmountVar;

 if ( (temp) < overdraftVar)
```

A Temp variable will make sure that the value of moneyAmount will not change.

Comment: thanks, I changed the condition to if ( (moneyAmountVar - withdrawalAmountVar) < overdraftVar) and now is working